# juju 2.0 bootstrap node root access

Tags: juju

If I want to su to root user in node0 after login as ubuntu how I can do that?

```
ubuntu@node0:~$ su 
Password: 
su: Authentication failure 
ubuntu@node0:~$
```

Is there any way to get root level access of the bootstraped node?? If I want to access the node0 from some other system which does not have juju installed how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the root account doesn't have a password. You can create one by running:

```
sudo passwd root
```

You will then be able to su with the password you just created.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to get root level access of the bootstraped node??

The *ubuntu* user is part of the *sudoers* group, which means it can use `sudo` to run a command as root.

> If I want to access the node0 from some other system which does not have juju installed how can I do that ?

This is an entirely separate issue, but you can add authorized SSH keys to allow additional clients to connect to Juju-managed machines. Use the `juju authorized-keys add` (`juju add-ssh-key` in Juju 2.0) command to add keys.